# Why do I got Promise pending instead of Express response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My code,I am new to Express.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   const name = req.query.name;
   const rank = req.query.rank;
   const headers = Object.entries(req.headers)
  .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`);
  
res.json({ success: true, data : { name, rank } , headers : headers });
});

server = app.listen(3000);

const res = axios.get('http://localhost:3000?name=John Malone&rank=Captain');

console.log(res);
```

Terminal output

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I changed my code,data output

```
  data: {
    success: true,
    data: { name: 'John Malone', rank: 'Captain' },
    headers: [
      'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'user-agent: axios/0.20.0',
      'host: localhost:3000',
      'connection: close'
    ]
  }
}

axios.get('http://localhost:3000?name=John Malone&rank=Captain')
   .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.data.name); // Data response from server
   });
```

Shows undefined.

Comment: Because `axios.get()` returns a promise.  So, when you `console.log()` it's return value, that's what you get - a promise.  Use `.then()` or `await` to get the resolved value from that promise.

Comment: Because axios.get returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two parts here:

- Server part is written by node (express) you do it right
- Client part is request by axios

You get Promise because `axios.get` return a `Promise` (an async request). So in that case I guess you want to log data to console. You should do something like this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000?name=John Malone&rank=Captain')
   .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data); // Data response from server
   });
```

Comment: How to get name and rank from output?

Comment: Well, it depend on your data, what is the result of `console.log(data)`?